# Spoof coordinates sent by a GPS tracker device

Tags: gsm, geolocation

Is there any way to change the GPS coordinates with fake ones? Eg. make a GPS tracker with a GSM modem for car tracking report fake coordinates for a short period of time before returning back to normal.

Comment: Android has an option to mock locations, you might want to install an app that uses this debug option to fake the location.

Comment: Yes, this has been [demonstrated](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/07/31/80-million-yacht-hijacked-by-students-spoofing-gps-signals/) several times already

Comment: @Hollowproc, I rejected the edit because the author was specifically asking how to spoof the "output" of a GPS tracker, not necessarily spoofing the input GPS signals themselves.  That doesn't negate that spoofing the GPS signals is likely the easiest way to accomplish the task, and your answer still contains the best information as to how to do this today.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how creative you want to get (and how much money you want to spend), there is a lot you can do with SDR (software defined radio) in terms of broadcasting GPS data using tools like the [HackRF One](https://greatscottgadgets.com/hackrf/) and the [BladeRF](http://www.nuand.com/). The reality is that any SDR device that has transmit capability should (in theory) be able to spoof GPS data. Many devices, including handhelds, smartphones, and tablets still implicitly trust GPS data.

More info on spoofing with SDR:

- [Talk at BlackHat](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-15/materials/eu-15-Kang-Is-Your-Timespace-Safe-Time-And-Position-Spoofing-Opensourcely-wp.pdf)
- [RTL-SDR](http://www.rtl-sdr.com/spoofing-gps-locations-with-low-cost-tx-sdrs/) (a good reference site in general)
- DEFCON 23 [Presentation](https://media.defcon.org/DEF%20CON%2023/DEF%20CON%2023%20presentations/DEFCON-23-Lin-Huang-Qing-Yang-GPS-Spoofing.pdf) Slide Deck
- Open Source Project on [GitHub](https://github.com/osqzss/gps-sdr-sim)

Remember, to be legal, you **technically** need a HAM Radio Operator's License to transmit.... *technically*.

Comment: *"to be legal, you technically need a HAM Radio Operator's License to transmit"* An amateur radio license only allows you to transmit on the amateur radio bands and only within the amateur radio regulations. While radio amateurs have large privileges, an amateur radio license is *not* a carte blache to transmit at any frequency you like. Particularly, if you try to transmit on a frequency which is used for military purposes, chances are that it *will* get someone interested.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling valid point. OP make sure to read this ^ if you go the SDR route.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to either attack the device itself to alter its firmware and to report the data you wish. See if it has a serial port or firmware update feature, analyze the old firmware and add your "fake location" feature.

If attacking the device isn't possible, you can broadcast fake GPS data and hope that the device picks up your fake broadcasts (which can appear as any location you wish) and then transmits them as usual.

Finally if simulating a GPS signal is impossible, you could directly attack how it reports its data - if it uses SMS you can simply jam its signal to prevent it from sending the real data and in the meantime send texts to the destination server with your fake location and spoof the number so it appears as if it came from the tracker itself. This assumes the tracker doesn't store a log of locations while network was unavailable so it can resend them later.

The second option would be to jam secure bands like 3G and later, then spoof a base station, crack the legacy GSM/EDGE encryption so you can tamper with its traffic in real-time. You can now look at what it's sending, discard its own packets and insert your own ones. This will work even for data sessions such as GPRS - where you can't easily spoof an IP address like you could with SMS (unless it uses UDP and doesn't require a reply).

Answer (score 0):

The spoofing of GPS is not just a theoretical possibility. See the [experiment](http://m.theregister.co.uk/2013/07/29/texas_students_hijack_superyacht_with_gpsspoofing_luggage/) conducted in 2013 by students of the University of Texas:

> Students from the University of Texas successfully piloted an $80m superyacht sailing 30 miles offshore in the Mediterranean Sea by overriding the ship's GPS signals without any alarms being raised.

Answer (score -1):

If it's an OBD vehicle tracker, just unplug it and plug into an OBD GPS power adapter. Looks like your home or work (wherever you plugged it in) but you can of course just drive wherever then plug back into vehicle when done.

They sell them on Amazon.